# How do I get around my omniscient character isn't knowledge of the future?

Tags: characters, plot, fantasy

I've got a story with mythology and gods. But one of the main characters is Chronos, the God of Time, and I don't see how I can get around the fact that Chronos should have been able to prevent the story's conflict and tragedy from happening.

**Background**

This world was created by Natura, the goddess of space, creation, and life.

She felt alone, so she created Chronos, the god of time, destruction and death, to have a partner and also to maintain a perfect balance in the world.

Eventually, they had a child, Adam. Adam needed some company, so Natura remembered what she did to fix the same when she was alone. She took the good part of his soul to create a new being, Eve. She was sleeping. Now that he is just evil, he can rule the chaos. He cut the head of Natura. Chronos looked at his son, and Adam become into a huge beast. They fought, and before the final blow, Chronos opened a portal to the moon, and Adam was sealed forever. Chronos tried to undo what Adam had done with Natura's head, she was right now, but she was empty, no soul was there. He sent the girl to the Earth, and since cannot create life or bring her back, he committed suicide. Eve have not been awoken and her brother Adam still sealed on the moon.

**The problem**

Chronos is the god of time, so he is supposed to know the past, present and future, and he could prevent Natura's Death.

**Question**

How can I justify that Chronos did not know? Alternatively: in the case that he did know, how can I justify that he did not act on that knowledge?

Comment: You thought up a story with a very faulty premise and want to remove that fault? This is not really a good story. Yes, I could find a plausible excuse if this question was asked on Worldbuilding.SE, but that would still be a contrivance, not a real solution. This is not how good writing is done. If you have a bad premise, you don't try to look for contrivances to patch it up, you change the premise.

Comment: Welcome to Writers. As this question is currently written, it's asking [what to write](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/397/26), something that we've decided is off-topic here. If you'd like to edit this into a question that we can answer on this site, please have a look at our site [tour] and help pages, in particular the page "[what topics can I ask about here?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"

Answer (score 2):

**This is ultimately not really a writing question** (since it has nothing to do with how you'll *write* the story). I'd suggest asking it in worldbuilding instead (since it relates to the practical limitations of fantastical concepts, I'd say it's on topic there). That said, here are a few suggestions:

- Perhaps Chronos knows what will happen if he acts on the knowledge, and knows that it's even worse (or that what he'd have to do to prevent it is unthinkable to him).
- Perhaps Chronos doesn't know what will happen if he acts on the knowledge, and is too paralysed by the fear that it *could* be worse to do anything.
- Perhaps he tries to prevent it and ends up causing it. Obviously, he will know that he is causing it as he acts, so this will need to be something with sufficient emotional weight that he can't resist the impulse to act, even though he knows the consequences.

These are by no means the only possibilities, but it all comes down to the kind of story you're trying to tell (and particularly the kind of story arc you want for the character). Do you want him to be watching, horrified, as events unfold; absent mindedly oblivious; frantically trying to change things, but failing? I suggest that you decide this first, and let the worldbuilding follow naturally from it.